# How do I pass django variables to javascript in a for statement?

Tags: javascript, html, django

How do I pass django variables to javascript in a for statement I want to pass c.tv.tv_id in a for statement in javascript. I want to pass it to javascript in each for statement, but I don't know how to do it.

```
class Comment_List_TV(ListView):
      template_name = 'account/user_comment_list_tv.html'
      def get_queryset(self):
            Comment_list_query = Comment_tv.objects.none()
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                  Comment_list_query = Comment_tv.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            return Comment_list_query
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%load static%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css\common_movie_tv.css' %}">
{% block content %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>created_at</th>
            <th>comment</th>
            <th>evaluation</th>
        </tr>
        {% for c in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <th id = "trendings"></th>
                <td>{{ c.user.nickname }}</td>
                <td>{{c.tv.tv_id}}</td>
                <td>{{ c.created_at }} </td> 
                <td>{{ c.comment }}</td>
                <td><h2 class = "rate" style="--rating:{{c.stars}}">{{c.stars}}</h2></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<script>
    const tv_id = {{c.tv.tv_id}}
    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${tv_id}?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
        mainDiv.setAttribute("class", "card");
        mainDiv.setAttribute("style", "width: 18rem;");
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200" + data.poster_path);
        img.setAttribute("class", "card-img-top");
        img.setAttribute("alt", "...");
        var body = document.createElement("div");
        body.setAttribute("class", "card-body");
        var title = document.createElement("h5");
        title.setAttribute("class", "card-title");
        if (data.name) {
            title.innerHTML = data.name;
        } else {
            title.innerHTML = data.title;
        }
        //var text = document.createElement("p");
        //text.setAttribute("class", "card-text");
        //text.innerHTML = data.results[i].overview;
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", "/" + "tv" + "/" + data.id + "/");
        link.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
        link.innerHTML = "View Details";
        body.appendChild(title);
        //body.appendChild(text);
        body.appendChild(link);
        mainDiv.appendChild(img);
        mainDiv.appendChild(body);
        document.getElementById("trendings").appendChild(mainDiv);
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

How do I pass django variables to javascript in a for statement I want to pass c.tv.tv_id in a for statement in javascript. I want to pass it to javascript in each for statement, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Show me the views.py request.

Comment: It depends, how are you sending the data from your view.

Comment: I added views.py in django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need put your query result in a dict and send it as a Json response.

Pre-Django 1.7 you'd return it like this:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

For Django 1.7+, use JsonResponse as shown in this SO answer like so :

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```